# Firefox webextension not copying to clipboard

Tags: javascript, firefox, clipboard, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a Firefox web extension which is supposed to generate buttons which copy a link to the clipboard. In my content script for the plugin, I have:

```
    button.onclick = function() {
        var link = window.location.href.replace(/#[0-9a-zA-Z_]+$/, '') + '#' + id;
        var txtToCopy = document.createElement('input');
        txtToCopy.value = link;
        txtToCopy.select();

        console.log(txtToCopy.value);
        var res = document.execCommand('copy');
        console.log(res);

    }
```

As you can see, I have it logging the value I'm trying to copy, as well as the result returned from `execCommand`. Both are what I'd expect.

`"https://thing.example.com#12345"
true`

However, it does not appear to actually copy the text to the clipboard. According to MDN, I shouldn't need any extra permissions as it's is happening in an event, and the response from `execCommand` makes me thing everything is setup as needed.

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04, Firefox 51.0.1, with e10s enabled. Maybe e10s is my problem, will give update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to append `txtToCopy` to the DOM to copy from it and it has to be "visible" (more or less).

```
button.onclick = function() {
    var link = window.location.href.replace(/#[0-9a-zA-Z_]+$/, '') + '#' + id;
    var txtToCopy = document.createElement('input');
    txtToCopy.style.left = '-300px';
    txtToCopy.style.position = 'absolute';
    txtToCopy.value = link;
    document.body.appendChild(txtToCopy);
    txtToCopy.select();

    console.log(txtToCopy.value);
    var res = document.execCommand('copy');
    console.log(res);

    txtToCopy.parentNode.removeChild(txtToCopy);

}
```

Comment: That was it (almost)! One small change, the select() has to happen after being appended to the document, apparently. Thanks